# Can't withdraw amount from contract on Ethereum local blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, contract, ether

I am having an issue that is blocking me for days. And it all comes down to this:

I am using Ganache (TestRPC) for my local blockchain with it's default test accounts. 
I am connected with Metamask(on Chrome) using the first test account. (balance 100ETH).

I am creating the WithdrawalContract from solidity documentation: 
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html 
using 10ETH.
Everything fine until now. Contract creation successful, my test account balance is 90ETH and Contract shows in transactions list with 10ETH.

Now I execute the `withdraw()` that should refund me the 10ETH amount.

Metamask shows transaction as success.

But the amount never makes it to my test account. Account balance is still 90ETH.

What am I missing? Why isn't withdrawal working for me?

PS: I do all this using `remix.ethereum.org`, using same account for contract creation and withdrawal. I also tried it with `truffle` but i got the same result.

Comment: Can you post the steps you took with the contract? I just tried it and it worked fine.

Comment: I made a video recording with all the steps I went trough from scratch. All apps use default settings:   https://youtu.be/dD2fkPxpk_E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the video from your comment. This is just a simple example contract on the Solidity site and is not written very well. You have to pay closer attention to the code. `withdraw()` uses the `pendingWithdrawals` mapping to determine how much the caller is allowed to transfer out of the contract. Only the `becomeRichest()` method is setting that mapping. The constructor is not.

Deploy the contract without sending any ether. Then call `becomeRichest()`, this time sending in the ether. Then use `withdraw` (or, improve the code).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed the code to also add `msg.sender` and `msg.value` to `pendingWithdrawals` in the `constructor` and it seems to work fine. Also removing and installing Metamask again fixed some invalid address errors I got. Finally, in remix you can use the Javascript VM which does not need Metamask, it is easier for debugging contracts.

Answer (score 0):

can you try using transfer() and see

The code will look something like this

msg.sender.transfer(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'ether'));

`msg.sender` => the address interacting with the contract at that point of time and also the address that needs to be receiving the money as transfer() is called on that address ( in this case its you)